# How to mock new instance of RestTemplate?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, resttemplate, powermockito

Im writing a unit test for my legacy code which is something like:

```
public class SomeClass {
public SomeResponse logToServer() {
    SomeResponse response = null;
    try{ 
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        SomeRequestBean request = new SomeRequestBean();
        response = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://someUrl", request, SomeResponse.class);
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return response;
}
```

}

I know I can move RestTemplate above and annotate it as `@AutoWire` and declare it as bean class or use power mockito to mock the new instance creation. But I don't wanna change this legacy code and I'm avoiding using power Mockito at all cost because just for one test I don't wanna add a whole new dependency to my `pom.xml`. So just wondering is there any way using which I can mock this **restTemplate** ?

Comment: That's not your real code, this won't compile in a class declaration. Please show something compilable so eerie have to guess what goes where (class or method code).

Comment: I've edited the code. However i cannot share the exact Enterprise  level code. but it looks something like the above.

Comment: @James based on stated restrictions, then I would say,  **no**, There is likely no other way to mock the `restTemplate`. The subject code is tightly coupled to implementation concerns that make testing it in isolation difficult without out external dependencies/tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer you question, no under the restrictions you've posted there is no way to mock RestTemplate and **unit test** it.

I do think that you can slightly change the legacy code because this change is not functional and in this case it might worth it. But I'll stick with you that you can't.

Regarding power mock and power mockito. Although I agree that these tools should be avoided but not for a reason that you've posted. Note, that this dependency is of test scope, it won't reach the production anyway even for legacy envrionments. So if the priority is to not change the legacy code, then introducing PowerMock is the "least evil".

If we're talking specifically about the rest template though, you can take advantage of some facts about spring rest template specifically that can be used for testing it anyway.

**Option 1**

The first technique (if the environment permits) is using `@RestClientTest` annotation. It will allow specifying the service under test and will provide a mock implemetation of something called  `MockRestServiceServer` that will represent the server you're trying to connect to in the mocked environment. Then you'll be able to specify the expectations from this server and hopefully the code will run. Caution: this is not a unit test - this is an integration test that starts spring context, so it will much heavier/slower than regular unit test.

[Here](https://www.baeldung.com/restclienttest-in-spring-boot) you can find a working example of this approach, check out this article it contains also other techniques.

**Option 2**

The  idea behind the second technique is that `RestTemplate` is actually a wrapper above client libraries, it doesn't do any http intercommunication by itself.

It can be configured to work with HttpClient of apache, OkHttpClient, by default it works with URLConnection opening connection for each request. So You could create a test that would configure the rest client to run with some particular engine of your interest/choice and then check out how to test code that uses this engine directly. The solutions will be different depending on the actual engine used in the project.